# Getting Sphinx to filter search results

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx, full-text-search

I've installed [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) with the purpose of using it for fulltext search on a `MySQL` table (`InnoDB`).

Table columns consist of an `id` (numeric), `name` and `description` (these both to be fulltext indexed; actually there's some more, but for the sake of simplifying the question...), and `lang` (language identifier).

Indexing goes through without problems and I am getting correct results for simple searches.

However I run into troubles as soon as I try to query `name` and `description` for a specified word while filtering the results by language (`lang`).

I'd basically like to achieve the *equivalent* of (say the searched phrase was 'yerba') :

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE MATCH('yerba') AGAINST(name, description)
AND 'lang' == 'eng'
```

Not excessively ambitious, yet I must be missing something, because I keep on getting incorrect results. I am using Sphinx's PHP API:

```
$s = new SphinxClient();
$db = new DB();
$s->setServer('192.168.2.57', 9312);
$s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$result = $s->query("@* yerba @lang eng");

print (count($result['matches']));
var_dump($s->GetLastError(),$s->GetLastWarning());
print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';
```

20 matches are returned:

```
20
string '' (length=0) // no error
string '' (length=0) // no warning
Array
(
    [error] => 
    [warning] => 
    [status] => 0
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => lang
            [1] => name
            [2] => description
            // snip...
        )

    [attrs] => Array
        (
            [lang] => 7
        )

    [matches] => Array
        (
            [568] => Array
                (
                    [weight] => 6640
                    [attrs] => Array
                        (
                            [lang] => spa
                        )

                )

            [234] => Array
                (
                    [weight] => 6630
                    [attrs] => Array
                        (
                            [lang] => pol
                        )

                )

            // snip

    [total] => 44
    [total_found] => 44
    [time] => 0.000
    [words] => Array
        (
            [yerba] => Array
                (
                    [docs] => 44
                    [hits] => 238
                )

            [pol] => Array
                (
                    [docs] => 715
                    [hits] => 772
                )

        )

)
```

It's quite easy to notice that in the very first record it found, `lang` is `spa`, not `eng`.

Why??

The configuration file (`sphinx.conf`) looks as below - **source:**

```
source src1
{
    [...]   
    sql_query       = \
        SELECT id, lang, name, description // snip! \
        FROM my_table
    [...]
    sql_field_string    = lang
    [...]
}
```

**Index:**

```
index test1
{
    source          = src1
    [...]
    min_word_len        = 1
    [...]
}
```

All other options, apart from db access data, which works fine as I said (for non-filtered queries), are left as default.

I've been trying to crack this nut for a while now. I tried declaring `lang` as an `sql_attr_string`, using different match modes etc. alas, all in vain.

Do I have indexing set up wrong? Where have I messed up here?

Answer (score 2):

To make things easier, I suggest to change language from string field to integer attribute.

So, you query will look like:

```
$s->SetFilter('lang', array(1)); //1 - eng
$s->Query('yerba');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this...

> $result = $s->query("@* yerba @lang eng");

then...

> ```
> [words] => Array
>        [yerba] => Array
>        [pol] => Array
> ```

Are you sure they are for the same query? "pol" is not in your query

Otherwise check wordforms/exceptions, maybe you are transforming your text in some way...?